# Apply reduce function to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want this code to calculate sum of all 'age' fields (I want to use reduce)
Problem deals with fact that "age" is int

```
mylist = [{"email": "test1", "age": 35},
          {"email": "test2", "age": 32},
          {"email": "test3", "age": 38}]
reduce(lambda acc,curr: acc['age']+curr['age'], mylist)
```

I have error

> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I am using python2.7

Comment: I'd prefer to see: `sum([d['age'] for d in data])`. It's more readable. The `reduce` function is rarely the best option, imo.

Comment: How can i improve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Problem deals with fact that "age" is int

No; the problem is that your `acc` will end up being an `int`, which does not have an `["age"]` to access.

Keep in mind that each time through the `reduce` process, `acc` will be the *result from the previous step*, i.e., an `int` again. So you don't actually want to access its `['age']` in the first place.

But you also don't want to use `reduce` to add up a bunch of values, because it's harder to understand than just using the right tool for the job - `sum`.

Supposing we have

```
mylist = [{"email": "test1", "age": 35}, {"email": "test2", "age": 32}, {"email": "test3", "age": 38}]
```

It looks like:

```
sum(curr['age'] for curr in mylist)
```

which also has the advantage of working on 2.x and 3.x without changes. (In 3.x, `reduce` is no longer a builtin and must be imported from the `functools` standard library; it was shoved aside like that specifically to discourage using it like this).

But for completeness, the appropriate `reduce` call looks like

```
reduce(lambda acc, curr: acc+curr['age'], mylist, 0)
```

Again, `acc` will be an `int` at all steps during the process. But note that we also need to supply the initial accumulator value explicitly here, since the first element of the input doesn't have the desired type.

**The golden rule is that whatever is returned from your `lambda acc, curr` should have the same type that `acc` does.**

Sometimes you'll want to use a different value or type, too. For example, if you were implementing a product rather than a sum, you would want to start with a multiplicative identity (i.e., `1`). Or maybe you're doing some operation that returns a non-integer, that will keep returning a non-integer. (*Please don't use this to concatenate strings! The `.join` method is more efficient.*)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide an initial value, then `acc` starts off as the first element of the list. That would be really cumbersome to handle. Just start with 0, so you deal with ints instead.

```
>>> reduce(lambda acc, curr: acc + curr['age'], mylist, 0)
105
```